# Section within a section - UITableView -

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I just have a question with regards to the tableView.

I know we can return the number of sections and rows with.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Could you tell me how I can have something like :

> - A section within a section (and another section, if possible) - - And
>     then configure the rows there ?

And what would I return in

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to make your own implementation in cellForRowAtIndexPath where you return a row that is really made up of multiple rows and maybe a header label. Or maybe better is to make every other row a "header row" and check in cellForRowAtIndexPath whether you are on a "header row" or normal row; something like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
     // return header row
} else {
     // return normal row
}
```

and of course in numberOfRowsInSection you will have to return the normal amount of rows + 1 for sections with a header.

Comment: Sounds logically awesome ! what would I return in numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection ?

Comment: Well suppose you have 3 main section and section 1 has 3 sub-sections. numberOfSections should be 3 and you would return rows + 3 for numberOfRowsInSection when section == 0. One for the header and 3 rows. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath you would return the special header row only when indexPath.row == 0.

Comment: Sorry I mean (normal number of rows) + 3 header rows. 3 for the headers and then the normal rows. And you will now have to keep track of where you are using headers, so when in cellForRowAtIndexPath you will return a header for say row 0, 5,  and 8 in section 0. This means you have normal rows at 1,2,3,4 (sub-section 1), 6,7 (sub-section 2) etc. It will get (even more) complicated for sub-sub sections, but you could maybe generate the whole tree of them using NSDictionaries within NSDictionaries or something.

Comment: Just in case it can have an impact on the decision-making, I think that taking this approach will prevent you from being able to use cell reuse properly though.

Comment: The problem is that this "sub-SECTION" won't stay when the sub-section's cells scroll up like a real section header does.  How would one do that????

Comment: Yes its true that the section header doesn't stay as it is not a Header view and rather a custom cell. I too came across the similar requirement, any update on how the issue is solved would help me as well